# 現在運用されているサーバーで導入されているCALの数を知りたい

Tags: サーバー管理, windows-server

Windows Server 2012 Standard です。

新しいサーバー購入の際に、オプションでCALをつけるかという項目でいくつ必要かがわからず、現在運用されているサーバーはCALがいくつあるのか調べたいです。
どこで調べられるでしょうか？

また、ついでの質問なのですが、下記のような使い方をしているのですが、CALの数が1や10だった場合、どのようなことが起きるでしょうか？
同時アクセスができないだけなら、順番待ちが発生して重くなる程度？ それともリモートデスクトップ接続をしないなら1のみでも平気？
・事務所で使用するソフトの本体をサーバーに入れ、各PCのソフトの状態を管理する
・リモートデスクトップ接続は担当者の1接続以外は使用しない
・各PCからは使用するソフトやバッチ処理を除き、サーバーを操作しない
・人数は50～100人規模で、ソフトのアップデート等で1日1回処理が実行される程度（事務で常にサーバーのソフトへアクセスするわけではない）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

現行がWindows2012でこれから新規にサーバを購入するという話であれば、今の数を考えるまでもなくCALは買い直しです。ユーザー数なりデバイス数なり運用に応じて購入してください。

「ついでの質問」の内容を見るとCAL(というかWindowsのライセンス)について認識が誤っているようです。ユーザーCALならユーザー数分、デバイスCALならデバイス数分のCALが必要です。

相談に乗ってもらえる販売店さんを見つけて現状含めて相談された方がいいと思います。

Comment: 確かにユーザーCALとデバイスCALを混乱させていました。ご回答ありがとうございます。

Comment: 認識が誤っているというのは「ユーザーCALとデバイスCALを混乱」程度の話ではないので、きちんと知識のあるところにご相談されることを勧めする次第です。